# How can we retrieve json object from index action of a controller in mvc and fill in a viewmodel

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

In my quiz application I can call a controller's action and fill in my viewmodel using the ajax calls (as the code below) but how can I load the question object on the index action and fill in my viewmodel before I make subsequent ajax calls on submit button click. In simple words how to get Json object on page load and fill the model

```
var question = {};
// fill the viewmodel object.

$.ajax   
{
url: 'Tools/Survey/',
data: JSON.stringify({question : question }),
contentType: 'application/json',
dataType: 'json',
type: 'POST',
success: function (data) {
    // data contains next question and create the view accordingly
},
error: function () {
   // error
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `JSON.stringify`. Now you are sending one string. If you don't `stringify` input, values will be sent like in regular POST. Just write this instead:

```
data: {question : question},
```